# Something drops my 1521-portrequest for OracleOraDB12Home1TNSListener - what and why?

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall, oracle-12c

I'm quite desperate, running out of ideas for this continuos failure:

**I can't connect from SYS03 (with SQLdeveloper) to SYS06 Oracle Listener on port 1521.**
the other way round (OLIPP06/Sqldeveloper connects to SYS03/XE) it works

**Configuration**

**Windows-7 prof SP1** on both SYS03, SYS06
Both are connected in "Arbeitsplatznetzwerk" that former kind of WORKGROUP.

Oracle XE 11g installed on **SYS03**; **Oracle Enterprise 12c** on **Sys06**

I installed Nmap - Zenmap GUI on both computer and scan the other on.
On SYS06 Port SYS03/1521 is visible/open
On SYS03 Port SYS06/1521 is not visible  (but it should)

I fumbuled on the router D-LINK DIR-652 with port forwarding, nothing. I finally cleared all these router configurations, to prevent any sideeffects, and anyhow I'm on a LAN, my TCP packages shouldn't go to the outside world.

Windows Firewall on SYS06 is configured analog to the configuration on SYS03. In Windows Firewall protocoll I can see that some 1521 Port request from SYS03 are coming, but turned down (dropped). (Anyhow the flush of the protocol into the file happens more or less at random times, can I force this flushing somehow?)

I restart the computer.
I disabled the windows firewall on SYS06 completly. Still no connection.
I check and see that windows firewall service is still running. I stop it, deactivate it. ==> still no connection from SYS03.

What nasty piece of software is droping those 1521-Portrequest on SYS06?
I'm figthing with this now for hours, with no much results.

Is there something I have overseen?

Comment: Problem is solved. The Oracle DB was installed in wrong System Class, Thus the Listener didn't accept session requests on port 1521 outside of localhost.

Comment: Thanks for contributing to Super User.  Please post your answer as an answer for the benefit of others in the future with your same question.